# passing a child object value to callee class through pointer in C++

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

The original code seemed to make lot of confusion so I removed and added other explanatory code. Hope it would not cause the same confusion.

Consider this as `Main calss` (`something like manager class`)

hpp:

```
 private: std::vector<int>* _cache;
```

cpp:

```
 whatever* whatever::somefunction(const String& nothing)
    {
        const auto newWhatever = new whatever{nothing, _cache};
        return newWhatever; // not important
    }
```

---

`Other Class` (the class which does some work and return the result)

hpp:

```
private: std::Vector<int> _cache;
```

cpp:

```
     class OtherClass
{
    std::vector* _value;
    std::vector _result;
public:
    OtherClass(const string& nothing, std::vector<int>* cache) : _value{cache}

    void calculateresult()
    {
      *_value = _result;
      }
}
```

`returning value from the method is impossible as per the original setup`

I would like to capture the result obtained in `OtherClass` into the pointer of the `Main class`.

The purpose is: the `OtherClass` is temporary, it is going to be destroyed and re-created every 10 sec once. So I need to store the result of this `OtherClass` and use it for next instantiation of it. As you can see the instantiation of this `OtherClass` will happen from `Main class` it is like a manager.

When I debug, I do see that there is a address assigned for `_value` and dereferencing it may not work, I don't know.

But it fails during the assignment i,e 
`*_value = _result;`

left being T = QVector* and right beign QVector.

The exception at code: `qvector.h`

```
template <typename T>
QVector<T> &QVector<T>::operator=(const QVector<T> &v)
{
    if (v.d != d) {
        QVector<T> tmp(v);
        tmp.swap(*this);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: The initial code you show doesn't really match how you describe how that code is used. There's no `doSomething` in the `Child` class.

Comment: As for how to "pass" a value back to the "Parent" object, why can't `Child::doSomething` just plain ***return*** the value? It seems there's something missing from your code and description if that's not possible. So please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) for some help to improve your question.

Comment: `int doSomething();`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the pointer in my case is pointer to a QVector and I hit an exception when assigning the calculated value of child to parents value pointer. I will post the exception.

Comment: Can you post working, compilable, example code? Because your current code is hard to follow.

Comment: @Galik, In real case of mine, I can't return something, all I have to do is pass a value from Parent to the child as a pointer and make the child calculation result to store in the location pointed to by that Parent value pointer.

Comment: @Galik, understand, I will rewrite.

Comment: If you have a pointer, you *do* make it point somewhere? The member variable `value` in the `Parent` class don't have to be a pointer, you can get a pointer to `value` by using the address-of operator `&`.

Comment: In line `int LocalValue`, it should be `int* LocalValue`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude.. yeah that's one point I can use. Thanks.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I usually follow the same procedure of passing the reference, but I just tried to use pointer thinking it makes just the same meaning. But it is not. Thanks. If you want then can put this as an answer. I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple:

```
class Child
{
    int m_Data = 0;

public:
    Child(int Data) : m_Data(Data) {};

    int doSomething()
    {
        // Do something ("Child calculation") , for example:
        int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, e = 0, f = m_Data, r = 0;
        r = a * b * c * d * e * f + a * b * c + f + 5;

        return r;
    }
};
```

Use:

```
Child Chl(5);

int Result = Chl.doSomething(); // Result is 10
```

--

If you prefer to work with a pointer: ...You wrote: "pass a value from Parent to the child as a pointer and make the child calculation result to store in the location pointed to by that Parent value pointer.":

```
class Child
{
    int * m_pData = nullptr;

public:
    Child(int * pData) : m_pData(pData) {};

    void doSomething()
    {
        // Do something ("Child calculation") , for example:
        int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, e = 0, f = *m_Data, r = 0;
        r = a * b * c * d * e * f + a * b * c + f + 5; 

        *m_pData = r; // "store in the location pointed"
    }
};
```

Use:

```
int Data = 5; // "A value from Parent"

Child Chl(&Data); // "To the Child, as a pointer"

Chl.doSomething(); // Data is 10
```

--

- It can be a `std::vector` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is (note the * for Localvalue):

```
class Child
{
    public:
        Child (int* value) : Localvalue{value};
        int* Localvalue;
        int Resultvalue;
        void doSomething() {
            if (Localvalue != nullptr) 
                *Localvalue = Resulvalue; 
        }
};
```

That being said this is kinda bad setup. The child requires the owner to guarantee that the pointer passed remains valid for the duration of the Child instance life.

You can improve it by using `shared_ptr<int>`. Or by following the other suggestions on your question to return the the value from `doSomething()`. Even if you now return a vector, thanks to return value optimization, there should be no performance issue.

Comment: the first thing I did was to check if the pointer is null, but it is not, I see the valid address in the debugger for it, it just fails during the assignment.